# Infinite Parallax in Unity not working as intended

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is a bonkers of an issue. Please bare with me and do ask for any additional detail if you require it!

I tried this tutorial from [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zit45k6CUMk&t=57s) for creating an infinite parallax in unity that moves as the camera moves. Firstly, the camera is locked onto the player via a cinemachine which is the main camera.

Here is my unity editor screen:

[image: Actual scene in test scene]

Split up layers for showing the actual layers:

[image]

As you can see there are these three layers inside the Background Parallax layer, these layers are a single parallax scene with sprites replicated thrice and placed closely to one another. [Layer 1, 2 and 3 are the same collection of sprites duplicated in the scene]

Each child of the Layer 1, 2 and 3 in the hierarchy is just a sprite, for e.g.: A tree, or a bush or the ground beneath.

MainCamera Properties:

[image]

The camera is attached to the player moving around.

When the player moves forward, the layer is not being replicated when the layer is about to finish. Simply stated, it's not rolling over to give the infinite feel.

**The Issue**[The layers not 'arriving' in front of the player as he moves forward]:

[image]

Moreover, I tried to debug the game by going into the scene just to find that as soon as I hit the play button, all the three layers overlap with each other as opposed to how they are spread over. They just clog the camera as seen here:

[image]

I just want the parallax to be infinite as I move further on and not see a broken scene as seen above.

The Parallax code attached to childs(sprites) of each layer(Excluding Layer 1, 2, 3 as they are just empty objects used to tidy the hierarchy):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parallax : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float spriteLength, startpos;
    public GameObject cam;
    public float parallaxEffect;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startpos = transform.position.x;
        spriteLength = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float temp = (cam.transform.position.x * (1 - parallaxEffect));
        float dist = (cam.transform.position.x * parallaxEffect);      

        transform.position = new Vector3(startpos + dist, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        if (temp > startpos + spriteLength)
        {
            startpos += spriteLength;
        }
        else if (temp < startpos - spriteLength)
        {
            startpos -= spriteLength;
        }    
    }
}
```

The above code just moves the sprite in the x direction(left and right) as the player moves.
I believe that the rolling of layers is not happening due to the camera being attached to the player. Just a hunch. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Which values did you assign to the `parallaxEffect` variable for each of the layers?

Comment: It's a float value, for eg: 0.4 value in the SerializedField of a sprite in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just discarded the entire way of doing this parallax, instead I found another way of doing the infinite parallax. This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBol2xzxCOU&t=1s) on youtube helps you create an infinite parallax from scratch.

After creating the parllax, if you face issues regarding lag or jitter with the parallax, you can try the following techniques to see if it runs smoothly:

- Try alternating between FixedUpdate() and LateUpdate()
- Try changing the Interpolation on the player(Interpolate or Extrapolate or None). Try combinations with the above step
- Lastly, this worked for me: Try changing the pixel size of the sprites by clicking on the sprite and not the object. Mine was 100, but when I changed it to 64, it ran butter smooth

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have these reversed:

```
if (temp > startpos + spriteLength)
    {
        startpos += spriteLength;
    }
    else if (temp < startpos - spriteLength)
    {
        startpos -= spriteLength;
    }
```

You have it where if the position is greater than a certain position, then it adds the length. This would mean it's always greater than that position and always adding. Same for the other side. What you need is:

```
if (temp > startpos + spriteLength)
    {
        startpos -= spriteLength;
    }
    else if (temp < startpos - spriteLength)
    {
        startpos += spriteLength;
    }
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. But I did discover something, I believe that since the sprites are moving with different speeds (parallaxEffect), the sprites that are moving with slower speeds aren't keeping up with the sprites that are moving with faster speeds.